# yield(x) vs. (yield(x)): parentheses around yield in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.4, I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` here:

```
>>> xlist = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [yield(x) for x in xlist]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But this generates a generator object:

```
>>> [(yield(x)) for x in xlist]
<generator object <listcomp> at 0x00000076CC8E5DB0>
```

Are round brackets around yield required?

Comment: Its worth noting that the parentheses around `x` in your examples is not doing anything. `yield` is a keyword, not a function.

Comment: Don't use `yield` in a comprehension. It does something crazy that's never what you want, and it should really be a syntax error.

Comment: Epilogue: yield in a comprehension became a syntax error in 3.8

Answer (score 16):

The [`yield` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) can be used in two ways: As a statement, and as an expression.

The most common use is as a statement within generator functions, usually on its own line and all. It can be used like this:

```
yield <expr>
yield from <expr>
```

The yield expression however can be used wherever expressions are allowed. However, they require a special syntax:

```
(yield <expr>)
(yield from <expr>)
```

As you can see, the parentheses are part of the syntax to make `yield` work as an expression. So it’s syntactically not allowed to use the `yield` keyword as an expression without parentheses. That’s why you need to use parentheses in the list comprehension.

That being said, if you want to use list comprehension syntax to create a generator, you should use the generator expression syntax instead:

```
(x for x in xlist)
```

Note the parentheses instead of the square brackets to turn this from a list comprehension into a generator expression.

---

Note that [starting with Python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue10544), `yield` expressions are deprecated within comprehensions and generator expressions (apart from within the iterable of the left-most `for` clause), to ensure that comprehensions are properly evaluated. Starting with Python 3.8, this will then cause a syntax error.

This makes the exact list comprehension in the question a deprecated usage:

```
>>> [(yield(x)) for x in xlist]
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: 'yield' inside list comprehension
<generator object <listcomp> at 0x000002E06BC1F1B0>
```

Comment: if you meant `(x for x in xlist)` literally then `iter(xlist)`  should be used instead.

Comment: you probably want `yield from xlist`