# Why is print("text {}".format(yield i)) an invalid syntax whereas print("text {}".format((yield i))) is valid?

Tags: python, yield

I was going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/python-generator-send-function-purpose) SO question on the [generator send](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-342.html) function when I came across this code

```py
def coroutine():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print("From generator {}".format((yield i)))
c = coroutine()
c.send(None)
try:
    while True:
        print("From user {}".format(c.send(1)))
except StopIteration: pass
```

As you can see the author used `braces` around the `yield i`; and I don't understand why it is needed.

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for `str.format()` doesn't mention anything about the argument to format() to be of any type. I'm sure my confusion arises from the fact that I don't know what the yield statement does or what type is generated or made when it's called.

Can you help me understand why braces are needed around the yield in a str.format function call?

The compiler wasn't very helpful and so I had to ask this question

```
In [1]: def coroutine():
   ...:     for i in range(1, 10):
   ...:         print("From generator {}".format(yield i))
   ...: c = coroutine()
   ...: c.send(None)
   ...: try:
   ...:     while True:
   ...:         print("From user {}".format(c.send(1)))
   ...: except StopIteration: pass
  File "<ipython-input-1-024981190f27>", line 3
    print("From generator {}".format(yield i))
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I would say it is similar to the case `sum(i for i in range(3),0)` (syntax error) vs `sum((i for i in range(3)),0)` (ok). In certain circumstances, python require "extra" braces, even from human point of view they are not needed

Comment: Syntax error means it has nothing to do with `str.format`; the `yield` statement must be in parentheses (not braces) within an expression.

Comment: `yield i` is a statement. `format` arguments need to be expressions. By wrapping `yield i` with braces you turn it into an expression

Comment: For future reference, everything after a syntax error is unrelated to the error. 90% of this question is obfuscation; an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would've just compared e.g. `def f(): 0 + yield i` vs `def f(): 0 + (yield i)`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thank you. I was clearly looking at the wrong places to find an answer for this error. But @francis_duvivier's  and @Tomerikoo's answer clearly points me to the right direction. That `yield is a statement` and format arguments need to be expressions. But deciding to keep the question up - because there weren't many resources on the internet that helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [referenced generator article](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-342.html), you can read:

> I recommend that you always put parentheses around a yield expression
> when you're doing something with the returned value, as in the above
> example. The parentheses aren't always necessary, but it's easier to
> always add them instead of having to remember when they're needed.
> ([PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) explains the exact rules, which are that a yield-expression
> **must always be parenthesized except when it occurs at the top-level
> expression** on the right-hand side of an assignment.

So, since the returned value of `yield i` is used in and `yield i` is not a top-level expression on the right-hand side of an assignment, it must be parenthesized.

Also, some more info in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845447/4962858